# Android Soundpool output save to file or change pitch of audio file then save

Tags: android, soundpool

I have an audio recording then change the pitch of the recorded output then upload to server or save as file the audio(modified pitch). Is there any ways to that or do you have any suggestions? I already tried the soundpool to change the pitch but unluckily it seems there's no way to save the output.